# SwiftUI: Is there a way to create a list with single selection (like in iOS Settings)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently building my first iOS app with Swift UI and I was wondering if there is any standard way in Swift UI to allow for single selection in a list. Just like is the case in the iOS settings (see screenshot below).

[image: 1]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It is just a `Picker` in a `Form`, which is in `NavigationView`. See for example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58881338/12299030

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make List with single selection with SwiftUI 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613503/how-to-make-list-with-single-selection-with-swiftui-5)

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi ... this seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile found an answer thanks to example code on hackingwithswift.com

```
struct ContentView: View {
var strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

@State private var selectedStrength = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Strength")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< strengths.count) {
                        Text(self.strengths[$0])

                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Select your cheese")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way to tackle the issue is by building a list containing HStacks as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834220/14934149

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for single selection for SwiftUI ForEach

```
 @State private var selectedTimeSlotBtn: Int = 0
 @State private var timeSlots = ["15s","30s","60s","∞"]

 ForEach(0..<timeSlots.count) { item in
                                    Button {
                                        self.selectedTimeSlotBtn =item
                                    } label: {
                                        Text(timeSlots[item])
                                            .frame(width: 39, height: 26, alignment: .center)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            .background(self.selectedTimeSlotBtn == item ? Color("clifie_light_green_com") : Color("clifie_dark_gray"))
                                            .cornerRadius(12)
                                            .padding(.trailing, 2)
                                            .padding(.leading, 2)
                                    }
                   }
```